# Hibernate Migration from 5.6 to 6.2

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have recently migrated my Spring Boot application from version 2.7 to 3.2, which requires updating Hibernate to version 6 or higher. I am using a PostgreSQL database in the back-end. After the migration, I encountered a privileges error:

```
Hibernate: 
    alter table if exists XYZ
       alter column created set data type timestamp(6)
2024-02-28 12:58:05 WARN  o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table if exists XYZ
       alter column created set data type timestamp(6)" via JDBC [ERROR: must be owner of table XYZ]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table if exists cases 
       alter column created set data type timestamp(6)" via JDBC [ERROR: must be owner of table XYZ]
```

I am using Java 17, Spring Boot 3.2, Gradle 7.6 and Hibernate 6.2.1-final.

My question is, why were there no privileges problems with version 5.6? And what needs to be done to resolve this?

There were solutions to annotate the column "created" with correct annotations, such as @Column (columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP").

Also changed the data type of column from LocalDateTime to ZonedDateTime, but no results.

Here are the hibernate related configurations:

```
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      org:
        hibernate:
          envers:
            audit_table_suffix: _AUD
            revision_field_name: REVISION_ID
            revision_type_field_name: REVISION_TYPE
    show-sql: true
```

Comment: As a side comment, can I just recommend that you do not let Hibernate modify your production database just like that? Use Flyway or something similar instead and leave `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` on `VALIDATE`

Comment: This is for future planned to use Liquibase instead of Hibernate modifiying the prod Database. But before this I need to make sure everything is working fine with the migration.

Comment: Please provide your hibernate-related configuration